# Mysql Error Codes on which to Retry Transaction

Tags: mysql, transactions, error-code

I have few APIs which fail when the load on server is extremely high, predominantly one of the things that causes failure is Deadlock in Mysql/MariaDB Server.

So I decided to handle the application code to look for MySql error code 1213 for deadlock, and re-attempt that API after a minor wait.

So that got me thinking, what are other Mysql Error Codes, where it would be safe to retry the transaction? Is there any such list of mysql error codes?

Comment: @Mech I was hoping I would not need to go through 100s of error code myself, and someone must have had exact same problem earlier. Isn't this a very common problem statement?

Comment: Yes, just google _mysql error codes_ and you will find a lot of places with the list of error codes an d their description for example https://www.fromdual.com/mysql-error-codes-and-messages

Comment: You mean to say no one ever had this use case, and has to go through 700+ error codes one by one? You must be kidding